# How do i query on an individual table and compare columns to get a list of users

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a simple referral system that basically when someone sign up with your code it places the affiliate_id in the referred_by column of that user. example ID:3 afflicate code is used in ID 4,5, and 6 referred_by column.
My question is how do i query on list of the individuals i referred and how can i get the total number of people i referred.Would I have to use `wherecolumn`?

Example:
ID:3 page would show the name of ID: 4,5,6 and the total count which is (3)

Here is my code:

```
public function profile($name)
    {
        $user = user::where('name', $name)->first();

        $r = user::select('referred_by', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->groupby('referred_by')
        ->where('name', $name)
        ->get();
        dd($r);

            return view('profile.name', compact('user'));
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend using a relation on your User model. The below relation should allow you yo get all the users that the current user has affiliated. *Code Untested*

User.php

```
public function affiliated()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'referred_by', 'affiliate_id);
}
```

YourController.php

```
public function profile($name)
{
    $user = User::where('name', $name)->first();
    $r = $user->affiliated();
    dd($r);
    return view('profile.name', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: ok thanks so i should put referred_by and affilicate_id on a separte table and create a model for them, then build the relationship @nick

Comment: No, the affiliated function should go straight into your user model, and it should without creating any new models